# How necessary is human zygote cytoplasm for generating a human?

Tags: genetics, embryology

I'm primarily questioning the roles of genetics and cytoplasmic factors of zygote in generating a human being with a natural embryological process.

For instance, is there an experiment where we check if we get a human when we replace the DNA of a mice zygote with human DNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zygote itself is necessary because in the early embryo there is almost no transcription of its own genome, instead it uses mRNA deposited in the egg cell by the mother (see also [maternal to zygotic transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_to_zygotic_transition)).

That being said, I don't think any ethics committee would allow an experiment like this in the first place.

Comment: Agree +1. It would be interesting though to know if such DNA swap has been successful among other vertebrates species and we could try to generalize it to humans.

Comment: [mouse>pig here](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0014805)